# subprocess cannot find folder

Tags: python, subprocess

I simply want to execute some subprocesses form Python. As an example, I just change the directory with cd but it does not seem to work:

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

subprocess.run('cd ' + str(Path.cwd()) + '/h5_to_pb/', capture_output=True)
...
```

Throws error :

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd
>   /home/base/Documents/Git/Projekte/CelebFaceMatcher/h5_to_pb/h5_to_pb/':
>   'cd
>   /home/base/Documents/Git/Projekte/CelebFaceMatcher/h5_to_pb/h5_to_pb/'

When using the same command in the terminal, it works just fine. (Same error type is thrown with the actual command I want to run). What do I overlook? 
Thanks

**Edit:**

Thanks to Sven,  I also tried following:

```
prog = subprocess.Popen('cd ' + str(Path.cwd()) + '/h5_to_pb/', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
prog.communicate()  
if prog.returncode:
    raise Exception('program returned error code {0}'.format(prog.returncode))
```

Unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: I think what you trying to do is done by the ```subprocess.Popen()``` method

Comment: Hi Sven, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it did not work either. If I am correct, Popen is mainly used for an argument sequence. Even though my command looks like a sequence, it is just one command (cd foldername).

Comment: @FloridaMan Are you sure there is an 'h5_to_pb' directory inside the 'h5_to_pb' directory? I have a feeling that adding `'/h5_to_pb/'` after `str(Path.cwd())` is causing the problem here.

Comment: exactly. There is no h5_to_pb in the folder. But the pwd is the parent folder. As said, in the terminal this woks like a charm. When I tried the Popen, I also tried with Popen(['cd', 'h5_tp_pb'] ... ). This threw alread an error like "no folder 'cd' ".  There is some problem with the cd command. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not a program, it is a shell command (command for `bash` or `sh` or even `cmd.exe`). You can't call such commands directly, but you can run shell with such commands as argument:

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

subprocess.run(['bash','-c', 'cd ' + str(Path.cwd()) + '/h5_to_pb/'], capture_output=True)
```

Where `bash` is a shell, `-c` — execute next argument as command, and `'cd ' + str(Path.cwd()) + '/h5_to_pb/'` is a command.

Despite `capture_output` parameter this `run` output of this call is nothing, because `cd` prints nothing. You can make also a several commands in one shell call (and getting output):

```
subprocess.run(['bash','-c', 'cd ' + str(Path.cwd()) + '/h5_to_pb/ ; ls'], capture_output=True)
```

If you need run some program in different working directory — use `cwd` argument of `run` method.

Comment: This explains so much ! find /dir/* gave a not found error, cause bash actually expans this, while python doesn't. The fix does the job! bash -c find /dir/* . thanks!